# find android ABI value

Tags: android, abi, virtual-device-manager

I'm trying to debug an android application that a user has reported a particular problem with. I have created a virtual device but when it comes to the ABI version I'm lost as how to find out the version the mobile is using (if the mobile even uses this!).

(it doesn't help that I don't really know what this means / is used for)

Is there a way to find if the devices is using (armabi-v7a, x86, x86_64, x86(googleAPIs).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SUPPORTED_ABIS

Comment: Before API 21 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI

Comment: yeah i've read this before but I don't have the ability to test the device live, aka update the code on the app as this is an app currently in the app store. It was more a question of if it was possible to find the version from the existing android settings somehow. ( ask the user  that is experiencing the problem to look within the android settings somehow.

Comment: I assume that is not possible :/

Comment: "It was more a question of if it was possible to find the version from the existing android settings somehow" -- there is no requirement that the CPU information be available in any user-visible location, such as Settings > About.

Comment: In that case ask for the phone model number and look on gsmarena what processor the phone has and on wiki perhaps what the processor can do.

Comment: thats a handy site!! thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 6):

As stated in [Determining Supported Processor Types (ABIs) for an Android Device](https://handstandsam.com/2016/01/28/determining-supported-processor-types-abis-for-an-android-device/):

- Pre-Lollipop: From terminal type `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi`
- Lollipop and higher: From terminal type `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist`

[image: Using AS's terminal while app is running in physical device]